# Dynamic SQL value from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm working with a dynamic query right now and I need values from a table.

My query so far:

```
DECLARE @query varchar(1500)
SET @query = 
'SELECT Id,'
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(myTable.myDate AS date),120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50), CAST(GETDATE() AS date), 120)+'] then [Counter] else 0 end) ''0'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, myTable.myDate)), 120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS date), 120)+'] then [counter] else 0 end) ''1'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -2, myTable.myDate)), 120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) AS date), 120)+'] then [counter] else 0 end) ''2'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50), CAST(DATEADD(day, -3, myTable.myDate)), 120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()) AS date),120)+'] then [counter] else 0 end) ''3'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -4, myTable.myDate)),120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -4, GETDATE()) AS date),120)+'] then [counter] else 0 end) ''4'''
+ 'FROM [myTable] GROUP BY Id'
PRINT(@query)
EXEC(@query)
```

This wont work because it says "Multi-part identifyer "myTable" could not be bound." on rows 4-8.

Ive seen people recomending something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    id varchar(50),
    counter int,
    myDate smalldatetime
)
Insert Into #tmp (id, counter, myDate)
SELECT * FROM myTable
--GO                       --doesn't work either with or without 'go'
DECLARE @query varchar(1500)
SET @query = 
'SELECT Id,'
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(#tmp.myDate AS date),120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50), CAST(GETDATE() AS date), 120)+'] then [counter] else 0 end) ''0'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, #tmp.myDate)), 120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS date), 120)+'] then [counter] else 0 end) ''1'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -2, #tmp.myDate)), 120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) AS date), 120)+'] then [counter] else 0 end) ''2'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -3, #tmp.myDate)), 120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()) AS date),120)+'] then [counter] else 0 end) ''3'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN [+'convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -4, #tmp.myDate)), 120)+'] = ['+convert(varchar(50),CAST(DATEADD(day, -4, GETDATE()) AS date),120)+'] then [aounter] else 0 end) ''4'''
+ 'FROM [myTable] GROUP BY Id'
PRINT(@query)
EXEC(@query)
```

Still doesn't work. Please help!

**SIMPLIFIED VERSION OF MY PROBLEM:**

```
DECLARE @query varchar(1500)
SET @query = 'SELECT ['+myTable.value+'] FROM [myTable]'
EXEC(@query)
```

doesn't work

Comment: `FROM #tmp` is what would be used if a temp table (called `#tmp`) was loaded up.. there *is* a table called `myTable`, right? That is, does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable` "work" when not in the dynamic query? Maybe the current schema is different than expected? If so, does `[theCorrectSchema].[myTable]` work?

Comment: Yes, you made typo or mistake in query in second example, FROM #tmp

Comment: yes, the table "myTable" exists. if I do SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable outside of dynamic, it works. I've tried [theCorrectSchema].[myTable] and it doesn't work

Comment: Why do you need to use dynamic query?

Comment: Because I need the column names to be the 5 last dates. so for instance, the 12th of june it would show the 12,11,10,09 and 08th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    id varchar(50),
    counter int,
    myDate smalldatetime
)
Insert Into #tmp (id, counter, myDate)
SELECT * FROM myTable

DECLARE @query varchar(1500)
Select @query = 
'SELECT Id,'
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN ''' + convert(varchar(50), #tmp.myDate,120) + ''' = '''+convert(varchar(50), GETDATE(), 120)+''' then ''counter'' else 0 end) ''0'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN '''+convert(varchar(50), DATEADD(day, -1, #tmp.myDate), 120)+''' = '''+convert(varchar(50),DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()), 120)+''' then ''counter'' else 0 end) ''1'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN '''+convert(varchar(50), DATEADD(day, -2, #tmp.myDate), 120)+''' = '''+convert(varchar(50),DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()), 120)+''' then ''counter'' else 0 end) ''2'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN '''+convert(varchar(50), DATEADD(day, -3, #tmp.myDate), 120)+''' = '''+convert(varchar(50),DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()), 120)+''' then ''counter'' else 0 end) ''3'','
+ 'SUM(CASE WHEN '''+convert(varchar(50), DATEADD(day, -4, #tmp.myDate), 120)+''' = '''+convert(varchar(50),DATEADD(day, -4, GETDATE()), 120)+''' then ''counter'' else 0 end) ''4'''
+ ' FROM ' from #tmp 
Set @query = @query + ' #tmp GROUP BY Id'
PRINT(@query)
EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. It doesn't like the seccond "from" in the line "+ ' FROM ' from #tmp". and it still wont let me use #tmp.myDate above

Comment: sorry. Still "The multi-part identifier "#tmp.myDate" could not be bound

Comment: You are using the query exactly as I have written? I did not get any errors.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Dont know why it wouldn't work last time. Must have copied it wrong some how ^^